# Не работают файлы из wwwroot(css,js,images)

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, razor

У меня есть проект Asp.Net MVC

вот главная страница Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/general-styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main-style.css">
</head>

<body>
<header class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-top">
            <div class="logo-block">
                <div class="logo-block__icon"><img class="logo-img" src="images/logo.png" alt=""></div>
                <div class="logo-block__logo">Mipls.ru</div>
            </div>
            <nav class="nav">
                <ul class="nav__list">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_toggle" />
                    <label class="hamburger" for="checkbox_toggle">
                        <div class="hamburger__block">
                            <span class="hamburger-line"></span>
                            <span class="hamburger-menu">Меню</span>
                        </div>
                    </label>
                    <div class="menu">
                        <li class="menu__list">
                            <a class="menu__link" href="#">Главная</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__list">
                            <a class="menu__link" href="#">Найти компанию</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__list">
                            <a class="menu__link" href="#">Организациям</a>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="head-user">
                <div class="head-user__icon"><img src="images/avatar.svg" alt=""></div>
                <a class="user__btn" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Setting_profile_user">Аккаунт</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<main class="main">
    <section class="top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="top__inner">
                <h1 class="top__title">Mipls.ru - найди себе компанию</h1>
                <div class="top__text">Здесь ты можешь найти с кем сходить в музей, поиграть в компьютерную игру,
                    отправиться в поход и даже сходить на бизнес-тренинг</div>
                <a class="top__nav-link" href="#">
                    <div class="f-btn find-company">Найти компанию</div>
                </a>
                <div class="top__block-images">
                    <img class="top__images" src="images/figure-main.svg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="top__nav">
                    <a class="top__nav-link" href="#">
                        <div class="y-btn table-games">Настольные игры</div>
                    </a>
                    <a class="top__nav-link" href="#">
                        <div class="f-btn computer-games">Компьютерные игры</div>
                    </a>
                    <a class="top__nav-link" href="#">
                        <div class="o-btn sport">Спорт</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="opportunities">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="opportunities__title">Возможности сервиса</div>
            <div class="opportunities__content">
                <ul class="opportunities__items">
                    <li class="opportunities__list">Знакомьтесь с новыми людьми, которые разделяют ваши интересы, на
                        онлайн и очных мероприятиях.</li>
                    <li class="opportunities__list">Обсуждайте предстоящую встречу в чате</li>
                    <li class="opportunities__list">Получайте отзывы и награды от других пользователей</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="events">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="events__title">Предстоящие популярные мероприятия</div>

            <div class="events__inner">
                <div class="events__item">
                    <div class="item__block-img">
                        <a class="block-img__image-link" href="#"><img class="block-img__image" src="images/img1.png"></a>
                        <a class="block-img__category-link" href="#"><div class="block-img__category">Компьютерные игры</div></a>
                        <img class="block-img__icon" src="images/icon1.svg">
                        <img class="block-img__like" src="images/heart.svg">
                        <div class="block-img__data-creation">22 мая / 11:00 - 23:00</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item__title"><a class="item__title-link" href="#">Как увеличить узнаваемость бизнеса и привлечь новую аудиторию?</a>

                    </div>

                    <div class="item__text">На выбранных площадках будут встречаться эксперты, выступать
                        известные спикеры, проводиться мастер-классы... <span class="item__more"><a
                                                                                                     class="item__text-more" href="#">Читать дальше</a></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item__bottom">
                        <div class="item__block-icon">
                            <img class="block-icon comment-user-1" src="images/comment-1.png" alt="">
                            <img class="block-icon comment-user-2" src="images/comment-2.png" alt="">
                            <img class="block-icon comment-user-3" src="images/comment-3.png" alt="">
                            <img class="block-icon comment-user-4" src="images/comment-4.png" alt="">
                            <div class="block-icon comment-all">
                                <span class="comment-number">20</span>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <a class="item__bottom-link" href="#">
                            <div class="item__bottom-arrow">
                                <img class="item__bottom-img" src="images/item-arrow.svg" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="events__item">
                    <div class="item__block-img">
                        <a class="block-img__image-link" href="#"><img class="block-img__image" src="images/img2.png"></a>
                        <a class="block-img__category-link" href="#"><div class="block-img__category">Настольные игры</div></a>
                        <img class="block-img__icon" src="images/icon2.svg">
                        <img class="block-img__like" src="images/heart.svg">
                        <div class="block-img__data-creation">22 мая / 11:00 - 23:00</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item__title"><a class="item__title-link" href="#">Праздничная игротека от Hobby Bobby! Нам 5 лет!</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item__text">Напоминаем, что 22 мая нашему магазину исполняется 5 лет и мы приглашаем
                        вас на праздничную игротеку... <span class="item__more"><a class="item__text-more"
                                                                                   href="#">Читать дальше</a></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item__bottom">
                        <div class="item__block-icon">
                            <img class="block-icon comment-user-1" src="images/comment-1.png" alt="">
                            <img class="block-icon comment-user-2" src="images/comment-2.png" alt="">
                            <img class="block-icon comment-user-3" src="images/comment-3.png" alt="">
                            <img class="block-icon comment-user-4" src="images/comment-4.png" alt="">
                            <div class="block-icon comment-all">
                                <span class="comment-number">20</span>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <a class="item__bottom-link" href="#">
                            <div class="item__bottom-arrow">
                                <img class="item__bottom-img" src="images/item-arrow.svg" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="events__item">
                    <div class="item__block-img">
                        <a class="block-img__image-link" href="#"><img class="block-img__image" src="images/img3.png"></a>
                        <a class="block-img__category-link" href="#"><div class="block-img__category">Спорт</div></a>
                        <img class="block-img__icon" src="images/icon3.svg">
                        <img class="block-img__like" src="images/heart.svg">
                        <div class="block-img__data-creation">22 мая / 11:00 - 23:00</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item__title"><a class="item__title-link" href="#">Матч всех звёзд 2023</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item__text">На один день «ВТБ Арена» станет машиной времени и отправит болельщиков в путешествие по баскетбол... <span class="item__more"><a class="item__text-more"
                                                                                                                                                                             href="#">Читать дальше</a></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item__bottom">
                        <div class="item__block-icon">
                            <img class="block-icon comment-user-1" src="images/comment-1.png" alt="">
                            <img class="block-icon comment-user-2" src="images/comment-2.png" alt="">
                            <img class="block-icon comment-user-3" src="images/comment-3.png" alt="">
                            <img class="block-icon comment-user-4" src="images/comment-4.png" alt="">
                            <div class="block-icon comment-all">
                                <span class="comment-number">20</span>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <a class="item__bottom-link" href="#">
                            <div class="item__bottom-arrow">
                                <img class="item__bottom-img" src="images/item-arrow.svg" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <button class="events__slider-btn slider-btn-prev"></button>
                <button class="events__slider-btn slider-btn-next"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
<footer class="footer">
    <section class="footer__top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="footer__top-inner">
                <div class="footer__top-left">
                    <div class="footer__top-title">Теперь есть с кем играть!</div>
                    <div class="footer__top-btn">
                        <a class="footer__top-link-btn" href="#">
                            <div class="footer__btn">Присоединиться</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="footer__top-right">
                    <div class="footer__top-items">
                        <div class="footer__top-item-title">Игры и мероприятия</div>
                        <ul class="footer__top-list">
                            <li class="footer__top-item"><a class="footer__top-link" href="#">Присоединиться</a></li>
                            <li class="footer__top-item"><a class="footer__top-link" href="#">Создать свою игру</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer__top-items">
                        <div class="footer__top-item-title">Организациям</div>
                        <ul class="footer__top-list">
                            <li class="footer__top-item"><a class="footer__top-link" href="#">Размещение мероприятия</a></li>
                            <li class="footer__top-item"><a class="footer__top-link" href="#">Реклама товаров/услуг</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer__top-items">
                        <div class="footer__top-item-title">Помощь</div>
                        <ul class="footer__top-list">
                            <li class="footer__top-item"><a class="footer__top-link" href="#">Безопасность</a></li>
                            <li class="footer__top-item"><a class="footer__top-link" href="#">Правила сервиса</a></li>
                            <li class="footer__top-item"><a class="footer__top-link" href="#">Контакты</a></li>
                            <li class="footer__top-item"><a class="footer__top-link" href="#">Служба поддержки</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="footer__bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="footer__bottom-inner">
                <a class="footer__bottom-link" href="mailto:contacts@mipls.ru">contacts@mipls.ru</a>
                <a class="footer__bottom-link" href="#">Вконтакте</a>
                <a class="footer__bottom-link" href="#">Политика конфиденциальности</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
    
    @RenderBody()
</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

и тут все работает, css подключаются и т.д.

[image]

даже IDE подсвечивает ссылки на файл

вот есть другая страница Setting_profile_user.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link asp-append-version="true" rel="stylesheet" href="css/general-styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" asp-append-version="true" href="css/admin-style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header-top">
                <div class="logo-block">
                    <div class="logo-block__icon"><img class="logo-img" src="images/logo.png" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="logo-block__logo">Mipls.ru</div>
                </div>
                <nav class="nav">
                    <ul class="nav__list">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_toggle" />
                        <label class="hamburger" for="checkbox_toggle">
                            <div class="hamburger__block">
                                <span class="hamburger-line"></span>
                                <span class="hamburger-menu">Меню</span>
                            </div>
                        </label>
                        <div class="menu">
                            <li class="menu__list">
                                <a class="menu__link" href="#">Игры и мероприятия</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="menu__list">
                                <a class="menu__link" href="#">Безопасность</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="menu__list">
                                <a class="menu__link" href="#">Правила сервиса</a>
                            </li>
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="head-user">
                    <button onclick="menuPolsov()" class="user__btn user-client-btn">
                        <div class="block-menu-bnt">
                            <img class="menu-profile-btn-img" src="images/menu-profile-btn.svg" alt="">
                            <img class="menu-profile-icon" src="images/comment-8.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </button>
                    <div id="menuPolsov" class="dropdown-content">
                        <ul class="menu-profile__list">
                            <li class="menu-profile__item menu-profile__icon-profile"><a class="menu-profile__link" href="setting-profile.html">Профиль</a></li>

                            <li class="menu-profile__item menu-profile__icon-event menu-profile__item-number"><a class="menu-profile__link" href="setting-profile.html">Мои игры</a><span class="menu-span-profile__link">5</span></li>

                           
                            <li class="menu-profile__item menu-profile__icon-chats menu-profile__item-number"><a class="menu-profile__link" href="#">Чаты</a><span class="menu-span-profile__link">5</span></li>
                            
                            
                            <li class="menu-profile__item menu-profile__icon-support"><a class="menu-profile__link" href="#">Поддержка</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-profile__item menu-profile__last menu-profile__icon-exit"><a class="menu-profile__link"
                                    href="#">Выход</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main class="main">
        <section class="admin-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="breacrumbs">
                    <a class="breacrumbs__link" href="#">Профиль</a>
                </div>

                <h2 class="admin-content__title">Настройки профиля</h2>

                <div class="profile__inner setting-profile__inner">
                    <div class="profile__left">
                        <nav class="content__items">
                            <ul class="content__list">
                                <li class="content__item">
                                    <a class="content__link content__link--active" href="#">Основная информация</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="content__item">
                                    <a class="content__link" href="#">Дополнительная
                                        информация</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="content__item">
                                    <a class="content__link" href="#">Безопасность</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="content__item">
                                    <a class="content__link" href="#">Награды и рейтинг</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                        <div class="profile__btn-block">
                            <button class="profile__btn f-btn">Сохранить изменения</button>
                            <button class="profile__btn w-btn">Отменить изменения</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="profile__right">
                        <div class="profile__block-info">
                            <h3 class="profile__info-text">Основная информация</h3>
                            <div class="profile__block-title">
                                <div class="profile__block-logo set__block-logo">
                                    <div class="profile__img-logo">
                                        <img class="profile__logo-img" src="images/comment-8-logo.png" alt="">
                                        <img class="profile__logo-pensel-img" src="images/profile-icon-pensel.png"
                                            alt="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="profile__info-name">
                                    <div class="profile__name">Кирилл Артемьев</div>
                                    <div class="profile__desc">Критического успеха у меня ещё не было</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="profile__block-organization">
                                <div class="profile__info">
                                    <div class="profile__info-inner">
                                        <div class="profile__info-block">
                                            <div class="profile__heading">Имя</div>
                                            <div class="profile__description">
                                                <input class="profile__input" type="text" name="one-line"
                                                    placeholder="Кирилл">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="profile__info-block">
                                            <div class="profile__heading">Фамилия</div>
                                            <div class="profile__description">
                                                <input class="profile__input" type="text" name="one-line"
                                                    placeholder="Артемьев">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="profile__info-block">
                                            <div class="profile__heading">Номер телефона</div>
                                            <div class="profile__description">
                                                <input class="profile__input" type="phone" name="one-line"
                                                    placeholder="89869778650">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="profile__info-block">
                                            <div class="profile__heading">Email</div>
                                            <div class="profile__description">
                                                <input class="profile__input" type="email" name="one-line"
                                                    placeholder="artemkira98@gmail.com">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>



                                        <div class="profile__info-block">
                                            <div class="profile__heading">Город</div>
                                            <div class="profile__description">
                                                <form>
                                                    <select class="profile__organization" name="city"
                                                        id="select-organization">
                                                        <option value="">Москва</option>
                                                        <option value="1">Москва 1</option>
                                                        <option value="2">Москва 2</option>
                                                        <option value="3">Москва 3</option>
                                                        <option value="4">Москва 4</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

но тут уже ничего не работает, просто текст, а остальное не прогружается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и IDE не подсвечивает ссылки на файлы

что делать?

Comment: [Документация - Статичные файлы](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files). Внимание на то, как прописываются пути (цитата: `знак тильды ~ указывает на корневой каталог документов`).

Comment: Спасибо это помогло
вместо этого href="css/admin-style.css" нужно было написать вот так href="~/css/admin-style.css"